# Decreasing recyclerview itemview height dynamically, makes itemview layouts to overlap

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Setting the visibility of a view to **View.GONE** inside OnBindViewHolder, after two or three viewholders, the **layout is overlapped with the previous viewholder** leaving a blank space at the bottom. The problem exist only when the visibility is set to GONE(*Itemview height decreases*) and not when its set to VISIBLE.

The Recyclerview height is set to "MATCH_PARENT" because I want it to occupy the whole screen and the viewholder parent layout is set to "WRAP_CONTENT".

Itemview/Viewholder layout

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="366dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            ..
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

When the visibility of the Textview is set to GONE. The layout overlaps with the previous viewholder. 
But the issue seems to be random with certain viewholders.

I also checked if the problem is with viewholders being recycled by setting the isRecyclable(false) but the issue still exists randomly.

Comment: change gone to invisible

Comment: any reason for setting visibility to `GONE`? if you dont want to show some items simply filter them out from the adapter

Comment: @pskink When a certain condition is met , on button click, the visibility has to be set to GONE dynamically. I did not understand what you meant by filtering from the adapter, could be please explain?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta It works fine when the visibility is set to INVISIBILE. But I have to set it to GONE. ie not show that the view bounds exist

Comment: use linear layout for that not relative and again develop that UI according to linear layout

Comment: `"I did not understand what you meant by filtering from the adapter, could be please explain?"` - see https://android.jlelse.eu/filterable-recyclerview-in-android-the-how-to-a9ade9cd26

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Thanks a lot!! It worked. Could you please tell me why it did not work for Relative layout althought all the view were arranged one below the other using the "layout_below" attribute.

Comment: because in relative layout there are dependency from each other for views and dis balanced but in linear layout no dependency they work on orientations not dis balanced

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Got it!